# Demonstrating convergence of an infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have the series
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n [\log(n)]^p}\;\;.
$$ I know that it will converge if and only if $p>1$ , but how can this be demonstrated?

My first intuition was to rearrange the denominator of the series to get $ \frac{1}{(\log(n))^{np}}$ - since $\log n$ will be positive, surely if $p$ is also positive, the fraction converges to 0 and then the series is convergent? I don't know how to formalise this argument, or if this is even the correct one.

Comment: Cauchy condensation test, if you aren't yet allowed to use integrals.

Answer (score 1):

The series
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^p}
$$
can be tested using integral test, since
$$
\int_2^{N} \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^p}dx=\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln N}\frac{1}{t^p}dt
$$
converges when $p>1$, and diverges when $p\le1$ as $N\to\infty$.

---

**Edit: How to integrate $\displaystyle\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln N}\frac{1}{t^p}dt$**

If $p\ne 1$, then $\int \frac{1}{x^n}dx = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}+C$, and $\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln|x|+C$. Thus$$\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln N}\frac{1}{t^p}dt=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1-p}((\ln N)^{1-p}-(\ln 2)^{1-p}),&p\ne 1\\
\ln\ln N - \ln \ln 2,&p=1
\end{cases} $$

Comment: How do you know that the latter interval converges and diverges when $p>1$ and $p\leq 1$ respectively?

Comment: @user3677952 Well... because the series converge or diverge respectively, of course! :-)

Comment: @user3677952 I edited my post. Can you proceed from this?

Comment: I can't see how you know the behaviour of the integral depending on p; you've shown that it behaves differently at p=1, but I can't see how you use that to distinguish p>1 and p<1.

Comment: If $p > 1$, then $\frac{1}{(\ln N)^{p-1}}$ goes to zero as $N\to\infty$, and if $p <1$, then $(\ln N)^{1-p}$ goes to $\infty$ as $N\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

One misconception I should dispel from your question is that the series converges if the 'fraction' or individual summand tends to zero, which is not true. Unless I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

Let's use [Cauchy Condesation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)
: being $a_n=\frac1{n\log^pn}$ positive and not increasing, we have that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n<+\infty\;
\Longleftrightarrow\;\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2^na_{2^n}<+\infty\;.
$$

But
$$
2^na_{2^n}=\frac{2^n}{2^n[\log(2^n)]^p}=\frac1{\log^p2}\frac1{n^p}
$$
hence
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}2^na_{2^n}=
\frac1{\log^p2}\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac1{n^p}
<+\infty\;
\Longleftrightarrow\;p>1
$$
as wanted.